# creating C# treeView from 4 lists

Tags: c#, treeview

The hierarchy and the relations of the classes i use can be visualized like this:

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzgwl.jpg)

I also have the corresponding .cs classes written with the relations mentioned above.

now, i have the following lists:

```
List<Main_Subjects> msl = si.get_main_subjects().ToList();
List<Subject> sl = si.get_subjects().ToList();
List<Mini_subjects> mnsl = si.get_mini_subjects().ToList();
List<Text> tl = si.get_texts().ToList();
```

ignore the si.get... statements. these just fill up the lists with data from the web service. These lists are filled with data.

Each "Main_Subject" has a number of "Subject"s.
Each "Subject" has a number of "Mini_Subject"s.
Each "Mini_Subject" has a number of "Text"s.

All properties of the classes are set to public so you can access them directly by `.property`

My goal is to create a TreeView to view the hierarchy i have described above so it will look some thing like this:

```
main_subject.name
                  subject.name
                               mini_subject.name
                                                 text.name
                                                 text.name
                  subject.name
                               mini_subject.name
                                                 text.name
main_subject.name
                  subject.name
                               mini_subject.name
                                                 text.name
                                                 text.name
                  subject.name
                               mini_subject.name
                                                 text.name
                                                 text.name
```

It is also important to store not only the name in the TreeView but also the object that corresponds to the name viewed.

the hierarchy is set like this:

```
1)Main_Subject
2)Subject
3)Mini_Subject
4)Text
```

Iv'e tried creating nested `foreach` loops, but came up with no result. 
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

This is what i have so far and it has problems:
(igrone the localhost. statements. these are there because of the web service).

```
    public void fill_tree()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (localhost.Main_Subjects a in msl)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(a.name);
            treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Tag = a;
            foreach (localhost.Subject b in sl)
            {
                if (b.main_subject_id == a.main_subject_id)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes.Add(b.name);
                    treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Tag = b;

                    foreach (localhost.Mini_subjects c in mnsl)
                    {
                        if (c.subject_id == b.subjects_id)
                        {
                            treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes.Add(c.name);
                            treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Tag = c;

                            foreach (localhost.Text d in tl)
                            {
                                if (d.mini_subjects_id == c.mini_subjects_id)
                                {
                                    treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes.Add(d.name);
                                    treeView1.Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Nodes[cnt].Tag = d;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            cnt++;
        }

    }
```

the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of
>   valid values.

Comment: Have you tried using child nodes?

Comment: What do you mean? @AlfieMcNarutoad

Comment: The issue here is that you are reusing the cnt index at every level in the hierarchy - this is not valid as when adding the second root item there will not be a second sub-item already present. You need to maintain a separate index at each level, or preferably just keep a reference to each node at each level as it is being processed to avoid the repeated indexing.

Comment: What do you mean by reference to each node? How exactly? Can you add example code? @BenJackson

Comment: Sorry for the delay, please see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a single variable `cnt` to store multiple indexes at different levels, whereas you need to maintain a separate index for eahc level.  Additionally the use of indexes here is suboptimal and probably undesirable.  Please try the below, which stores a reference to the current node at each level rather than relying on indexing.

```
        public void fill_tree()
        {
            foreach (localhost.Main_Subjects a in msl)
            {
                var node0 = treeView1.Nodes.Add(a.name);
                node0.Tag = a;
                foreach (localhost.Subject b in sl)
                {
                    if (b.main_subject_id == a.main_subject_id)
                    {
                        var node1 = node0.Nodes.Add(b.name);
                        node1.Tag = b;

                        foreach (localhost.Mini_subjects c in mnsl)
                        {
                            if (c.subject_id == b.subjects_id)
                            {
                                var node2 = node1.Nodes.Add(c.name);
                                node2.Tag = c;

                                foreach (localhost.Text d in tl)
                                {
                                    if (d.mini_subjects_id == c.mini_subjects_id)
                                    {
                                        var node3 = node2.Nodes.Add(d.name);
                                        node3.Tag = d;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```